# How to solve NoClassDefFoundException while junit test?

Tags: java, junit

I want to use JUnit tester to my Java program, but I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundException`. As I read this may got if I don't have `.class` file. But, since first I use it with `javac`, as I think it must be there.

Here is my command line:

```
myComputer\java\bead2>javac -cp .;junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
 snake\tests\ToApplesTest.java

myComputer\java\bead2>java  -cp .;junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
 org.junit.runner.JUnitCore snake\tests\ToApplesTest
JUnit version 4.12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: snake\tests\ToApplesTest (
wrong name: snake/tests/ToApplesTest)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandL
ineParseResult.java:100)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLinePar
seResult.java:50)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseRe
sult.java:44)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
```

Why this crashing for me?

Comment: You are specifying the test class incorrectly on the command line when you execute it.  The `java` expects a fully qualified class name, not a file path of some kind.  You need to review the basics of how to compile and run Java code.  Including, how the classpath works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `snake.tests.ToApplesTest`. You must provide a package name, not a path to the containing folder.